# javascript code making url link undefined

Tags: javascript

I am working on this javascript code and when is goes in the head and I refresh it goes to a 404 page.

Please can someone help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function recordOutboundLink(link, category, action) {
    try {
        var myTracker = _gat._getTrackerByName();
        _gaq.push(['myTracker._trackEvent', category, action]);
        setTimeout('document.location = "' + link.href + '"', 100)
    } catch (err) { }
}
$(document).ready(function () { $('#myid').click(recordOutboundLink(this, 'regular   xxxxx', 'xxxx.example.com')); });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the complete url to the method, ie, with the `http://` part

so either use:

```
.click(recordOutboundLink(this, 'regular   xxxxx', 'http://xxxx.example.com'))
```

or

```
.click(recordOutboundLink(this, 'regular   xxxxx', '//xxxx.example.com'))
```

Comment: Hello thanks for that, I did that but i am still getting the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to register the result of `recordOutboundLink()` as a click handler, causing the function to run first, evaluating `window.href` as the page to redirect to. The value of `window.href` is typically `undefined`, so the browser will try to redirect to `http://undefined` or something similar.

Instead, you should only execute the function when something is clicked, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#myid').click(function() {
        recordOutboundLink(this, 'regular   xxxxx', 'http://xxxx.example.com');
        return false;
    });
```

I believe the Google docs mention something like this:

```
<a href="bla bla" onclick="recordOutboundLink(this, 'regular crap', 'http://www.example.com'); return false;">tada click me</a>
```

**Edit**

Your locations should always be absolute, i.e. start with `http://`, `https://` or simply `//`.

Comment: Thanks Jack, I can't edit the HTML on this specific issue (cms plugin), so I only have access to the JS in the head. Thanks

Comment: @jelly46 Is there a reason why you changed the accepted answer? Didn't it work?